# Ipython double prompt after error within spyder

Tags: python

I am using Ipython 6.1.0 / python 3.6.2 in the anaconda distribution.
Within the spyder 3.2.3 iPython console, after an error, I get two input prompts, which prevents pdb being used in post-mortem mode [pdb.pm()].  Standalone ipython works fine.  Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: NB This problem persists with Anaconda3, viz:
spyder 3.3.2
python 3.7.0
IPython 7.2.0